# App Store App Name Change - how to leave old name for SEO / find-ability

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Recently I received an infringement notice regarding one of the words in my app name. I need to figure out how to change the name of an app, so that it won't confuse existing users.

Mainly, is there a way to change an app name so that it still searches under the old name (but, ideally, the old name does not appear)?

---

tldr I've received a trademark infringement notice for a for-fun app called Front Jacuzzi Back Corgi I made for my dog. It has a small loyal but unpaying following. Apparently one of those words is trademarked and can't be used, so I am considering renaming it to Front Jolly Back Corgi or Front Jetpool Back Corgi.

Comment: can you just replace Jacuzzi with Hot Tub? The J word being the copyrighted name of a manufacturer of hot tubs... Just curious...

Comment: right, but how do you do this so it doesn't cause confusion in case someone tries searching for "Front Jacuzzi"

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to new name and then mention the old name in brackets as well.

NEW NAME (PREVIOUSLY KNOWN AS OLD NAME)